# Detail of Proof of Theorem 6.17 in Probability Theory (A. Klenke)

Tags: probability-theory

There is a part of the proof of Theorem 6.17 that I don't understand.

**Definition 6.16.** A family $\mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ is called **uniformly integrable** if
$$ \inf_{0 \leq g \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int (|f| - g)^+ d\mu = 0. $$

**Theorem 6.17.** The family $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ is uniformly integrable if and only if
$$\inf_{0 \leq \widetilde{g} \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{\{|f| > \widetilde{g}\}} |f| d\mu = 0$$.

If $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$, then uniform integrability is equivalent to either of the following two conditions:

(i) $\inf_{a \in [0, \infty)} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int (|f| - a)^+ d\mu = 0$,

(ii) $\inf_{a \in [0, \infty)} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{\{|f| > a\}} |f| d\mu = 0$.

I got to the last part, which is to show that uniform integrability + $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ imply (ii).

The idea of the proof: Assume $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly integrable. Previous part of the theorem already showed that this is equivalent to $\inf_{0 \leq \widetilde{g} \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)} \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \int_{\{|f| > \widetilde{g}\}} |f| d\mu = 0$. For any $\varepsilon> 0$, there exists $0 \leq \widetilde{g}_\varepsilon \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ satisfying $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} \int_{\{|f| > \widetilde{g}_\varepsilon\}} |f| d\mu \leq \varepsilon$. Choose $a_\varepsilon$ such that $\int_{\{\widetilde{g}_{\varepsilon/2} > a_\varepsilon\}} \widetilde{g}_{\varepsilon/2} d\mu < \varepsilon / 2$. Then
$$\int_{\{|f| > a_\varepsilon\}} |f| d\mu \leq \int_{\{|f| > \widetilde{g}_{\varepsilon/2}\}} |f|d\mu + \int_{\{\widetilde{g}_{\varepsilon/2} > a_\varepsilon\}} \widetilde{g}_{\varepsilon/2} d\mu \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

My question: Where was the $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ assumption used?

Comment: Finiteness of the meausure is not required in this part of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to show that $(i)$ implies uniform integrability. More precisely, since $\mu (\Omega) < +\infty$, every constant function is in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ and thus the infimum of taken over all $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ functions is less than the infimum taken over all the constant functions.

Comment: Thanks. The way I understand it, $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ is needed for (i) implies uniform integrability - simply because you want constants to be $\mathcal{L}^1$. It's not needed for the other direction (uniform integrability implies (ii)). Is this correct? The wording in the textbook was a bit confusing.

Comment: Correct. Uniform integrability implies implies $(ii)$,  even without the assumption that $\mu (\Omega) < \infty$. It's the part of the proof you wrote here.